# crop image selected from gallery

Tags: android

I want user to select an image from gallery, crop it and set it in an imageview.

Image is selected and android's built in crop functionality opens up. everything works fine upto here. but when I click save (after cropping desired part), i am not returned back to the activity, but the application just closes without any error.

Here are my codes:

```
public void changeAvatar(View view) {
    Intent pickFromGallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(pickFromGallery, OpenGallery);
}
```

Here is onActivityResult :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == OpenGallery && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        pickedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(pickedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        cursor.close();
        String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));
        thumbnial = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
        performCrop();
       // Picasso.with(this).load(imagePath).centerCrop().resize(280,240).into(pro_pic);
       // pro_pic.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath));

    }
    if (requestCode == PIC_CROP && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        thumbnial = extras.getParcelable("data");
        pro_pic.setImageBitmap(thumbnial);
    }
}
```

And here is performCrop method :

```
private void performCrop() {
    Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    cropIntent.setDataAndType(pickedImage, "image/*");
    //set crop properties
    cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    //indicate aspect of desired crop
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    //indicate output X and Y
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 280);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 240);
    //retrieve data on return
    cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
    startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
}
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong. Maybe share some of your main code?

Comment: nthng is wrong actually. i figured out that this happens only for some images. for ex, if image is selected for "Downloads" folder, application closes. but if it is selected from "Watsapp" folder, everything is working fine

Comment: Oh ok ok, may be a permissions problem then. I also had problems with crop and image stuff relating to different sized images at one point.